# How to make VBA code highlighting show up as a tracked revision in word?

Tags: vba, ms-word, highlight

My goal is to make a VBA Code that I can use on multiple documents that will highlight words of my choice so that I can review them. I have code that "works"(ie: Highlights all the words I put in a txt file), but  I have come to the issue that these highlighting changes are not effected by the track revisions in word.

If I preform other actions (such as replacing) while track revisions is on, word works as expected. Is their any way I can make the change in highlight also be tracked in the same way?
Here is the main body of my code I am using to highlight the words:

```
With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
  .Format = True
  .MatchWholeWord = True
  .MatchAllWordForms = False
  .MatchWildcards = False
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  .Forward = True
  For i = 0 To UBound(Split(StrFind, "~"))
    .text = Split(StrFind, "~")(i)
    .Replacement.Highlight = True
    '.Replacement.text = Split(StrRepl, "~")(i) (Commented out) 
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  Next i
End With
```

At the moment, regardless of whether track revisions is on or off, all the words are highlighted as expected, but I do not need to approve/reject it (it just happens)

I know how to turn Track revisions on and off within VBA already. I am just trying to figure out how to track highlighting changes. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You might do a Web search on AuthorTec Find and Highlight. It’s an add-in to Word that I wrote for the purpose you describe.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Dim StrFind As String, i As Long
StrFind = "Lorem ipsum~Maecenas porttitor~Fusce~Nunc viverra~Vivamus"
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
With ActiveDocument
  .TrackRevisions = True
  With .Range.Find
    .Format = True
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Forward = True
    .Replacement.Highlight = True
    For i = 0 To UBound(Split(StrFind, "~"))
      .Text = Split(StrFind, "~")(i)
      .Replacement.Text = "^&"
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Next i
  End With
  .TrackRevisions = False
End With
```